# Windows Biometric Framework fail

Tags: visual-studio, biometrics

My friend asked me to write a simple program that captures a fingerprint from the built-in reader on a computer and prints out some kind of identifier. I can choose operating system myself, like a laptop with Windows or Linux, or an Android phone.

I thought that would be simple, surely there are many API:s for this, and I noticed that Microsoft themselves actually provides an API for it. Since I can log into my win10 laptop with the fingerprint reader, I know that the reader works.

For some reason the example that Microsoft themselves provide in their documention does not work for me. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbio/nf-winbio-winbiocapturesample

I suppose that the people writing those pages forgot to mention some important aspect or step, perhaps there is a way to add permission somewhere in Visual Studio.

After rewriting and trying many things, at least I get ONE step further in the process, but it still fails.

Here is the current version

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Stdio.h"
#include "Conio.h"
#include "Winbio.h"
HRESULT CaptureSample();
void capture(WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle, int flag);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    HRESULT x = CaptureSample();
}

HRESULT CaptureSample()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    // Connect to the system pool. 
    hr = WinBioOpenSession(
        WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
        WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
        WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT,            // Access: Capture raw data
        NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
        0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
        WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,          // Default database
        &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
    );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"Start my fingerprint capturing...\n");
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_INTEGRITY);
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_PRIVACY);
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_SIGNED);
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_OPTION_MASK_PRESENT);
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW);
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_INTERMEDIATE);
    capture(sessionHandle, WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_PROCESSED);
    hr = WinBioEnrollCapture(sessionHandle, &rejectDetail);
    wprintf_s(L"WinBioEnrollCapture hr=%x rejection = %d\n", hr, rejectDetail);

    if (sessionHandle != NULL)
    {
        WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
        sessionHandle = NULL;
    }

e_Exit:
    wprintf_s(L"\n Press any key to exit...");
    _getch();

    return hr;

}

void capture(WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle, int flag) {
    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    PWINBIO_BIR sample = NULL;
    SIZE_T sampleSize = 0;
    wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = %d.\n", flag);
    HRESULT hr = WinBioCaptureSample(
        sessionHandle,
        WINBIO_PURPOSE_IDENTIFY,
        flag,
        &unitId,
        &sample,
        &sampleSize,
        &rejectDetail
    );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n Bad capture; reason: %d\n", rejectDetail);
        }
        else if (hr == E_ACCESSDENIED)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.");
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCaptureSample failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        }
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Swipe processed - Unit ID: %d\n", unitId);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Captured %d bytes.\n", sampleSize);

e_Exit:
    if (sample != NULL)
    {
        WinBioFree(sample);
        sample = NULL;
    }


}
```

and here is the result of running it:

```
Hello World!
Start my fingerprint capturing...

 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 1.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.
 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 2.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.
 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 4.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.
 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 8.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.
 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 32.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.
 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 64.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.
 Calling WinBioCaptureSample. Flag = 128.

 WinBioCaptureSample failed, access denied.WinBioEnrollCapture hr=8009802c rejection = 0

 Press any key to exit...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using another API, though your objective is not clear here. You can check the [CloudABIS™](http://www.m2sys.com/cloud-based-abis-automated-biometric-identification-system/?utm_source=Stackoverflow&utm_medium=Product&utm_campaign=CloudABIS%E2%84%A2) which is superscalar, biometrics-as-a-service (BaaS) matching system for fast deployment at lower costs. The API is provided by M2SYS TEchnology and they have an vast array of hardware also.

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointer, will definitely check that out! I'm curious why you said that I should try another API, is that microsoft api known to work poorly? My objective is to scan a fingerprint, and then print out some kind of ID calculated from the result of a set of recognition filters applied to the image.  Then the next step would be to compare the ID with other known IDs.